# Can "1054 Unknown column in order clause" be the result of an incorrectly killed mysql process?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I just got a `1054 Unknown column x.y in order clause` error inside phpMyAdmin on a query where I did not expect it, because

- The query used did not contain an ORDER clause.
- The query used cannot be faulty since it works fine on a database with the identical table schema.

The problem came up after I stopped a long running query by simply killing the mysql daemon from XAMPP Control panel.

A `REPAIR TABLE x` didn't help. I got rid of the problem by explicitly querying the column that allegedly doesn't exist (`SELECT x.y FROM x`) and then doing my query again - which then worked.

*Is it possible that stopping the mysql process like I did is the reason for this symptom?*

**EDIT:**
The query that produced the said error:

```
SELECT * FROM x AS tblA

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT z, y, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM x
    GROUP BY z, y
    HAVING count > 1

           ) tblB
ON tblA.z = tblB.z AND tblA.y = tblB.y
```

**EDIT 2:**
The original query that was running on a 300k row table when I killed mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM x AS temp1

INNER JOIN ( SELECT z, y, Count(*) AS count FROM x GROUP BY z, y HAVING Count > 1 ) temp2
ON temp1.z = temp2.z AND temp1.y = temp2.y

RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT whole.v FROM x AS tblA

INNER JOIN ( SELECT z, y, Count(*) AS count FROM x GROUP BY z, y HAVING Count > 1 ) tblB
ON tblA.z = tblB.z AND tblA.y = tblB.y

RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM x ) whole
ON tblA.v = whole.v AND tblA.w = whole.w

WHERE tblA.v IS NULL
) temp3

ON temp1.v != temp3.v
```

Comment: What was doing the query you interrputed?

Comment: The query was running from inside phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you asked - I also included the original query for completeness.

Comment: I just got the same thing, unfortunately it is very difficult to analyse this problem so I doubt anyone will report this bug. How do you fix this? Restart doesn't help.

Comment: nvm I found it http://stackoverflow.com/q/23295343/1839439