# phpMyAdmin error: #1054 - Unknown column 'systeem_eisen' in 'order clause'

Tags: phpmyadmin

Yesterday I removed a column called 'systeem_eisen' from a table.
Now when I click in phpMyAdmin at the table 'products' I get the error message:
`#1054 - column 'systeem_eisen' in 'order clause'`
I can't open the table 'products'. But my website still works(he used also the table 'products').

But when I export the table 'products' and I watch the code I see nowhere the word 'systeem_eisen'.

Comment: Did you set some sort of default `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: no, it is a realy simple table with only auto-increment and a few fields

Comment: Lazy way would be to add the column back in, look at everything (since it will be accessible) then remove the problem and the column again

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - I have insert the column back using sql,  now I can see the table 'products', but the weird thing is that when I click at explore in phpMyAdmin is see the sql text `SELECT * FROM 'producten' ORDER BY 'systeem_eisen' ASC `. maybe that is the problem

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For me the only way was to set the order to an existing column under the search options:
[image]

Answer (score 23):

Goto **phpmyadmin** database you will see the **pma_table_uiprefs**.  It stores thoses "cached" preferences and you could delete or edit them.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and none of these suggestions worked for me. The cause in my case was that phpmyadmin had a sort for the altered/dropped column and I needed to fix it. Here is what resolved it for me.

In phpmyadmin, select your database in the left navigation pane. You will see all your tables, and in this case we are interested in `'systeem_eisen'`. Once you've found the table click on `Structure`.

[image]

You'll now see all the columns in the table. All you should need to do is remove the sort or change it accordingly.

[image]
[image]

You should now be able to open your table.

Comment: For me, this sorting thing was under Search, if you expand Options at the bottom. But this was the tip I needed to make browsing work again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after I renamed a table. I was not able to Browse this renamed table with this same error saying:

> previous_table_name.some_column  not found.

So after changing the table name, go to the Search tab, open the `+Options` menu at the bottom. In Display Order, there will be no column set, for now, so change it to any column now from dropdown and save. Error resolves.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to see records with PHPMyAdmin but I could see structure the table. In my case, it was because the table didn't have any primary key.

Answer (score -1):

the problem with was not able to insert crated_at and updated_at 
 but when i inert them one by one it works and the problem was because of having underscore in my table name '_' https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4208/