# phpMyAdmin error after change column name #1054 - Unknown column 'xxx' in 'order clause'

Tags: phpmyadmin

I recently changed a column name in a MySQL table using phpMyAdmin from `customer_count` to `customer_viewed`.

I can successfully query the new field/table through my application however I get the following error message when I click browse on the table in phpMyAdmin:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'customer_count' in 'order clause'`

It is as if within phpMyAdmin has this default order by `customer_count` stored somewhere.

I cleared everything from phpMyAdmin -> `pma_table_uiprefs` but still no joy.

Note: When I change the column name back to `customer_count`, the browse displays successfully.

Is there somewhere else in phpMyAdmin that a cached/default setting could be hiding?

---

I just tried the above in Firefox and it works fine, so obviously the issue has something to do with Chrome.
Apologies as my questing is no longer a programming one but something to do with the browser.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browsers cache in Chrome?

Comment: Ahh, finally got it. I had cleared everything in chrome, but had to clear, shut down & start again.

Comment: It's been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295343/phpmyadmin-error-1054-unknown-column-systeem-eisen-in-order-clause

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the phpMyAdmin-related Cookies should do the trick.

Open Developer Tools, press F12, go to the resources-tab, then Cookies and manually delete all the Cookies like "pma..." and "phpMyAdmin" by marking each and hitting DEL oder BackSpace. You will have to relogin to phpMyAdmin after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the right place, where phpmyadmin stores information about columns.

This is the database "**phpmyadmin**".

1. The table "**pma__column_info**". Go to search and search the table name you need. Then change the field contents.
2. Table "**pma__table_uiprefs**" - the same operation.
3. Clear cookies, browser cache
4. Reload browser.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

The phpMyAdmin tool saves the order clause you probably did before. If you now delete e column but the cached order rule still remains, it gives you this error. My solution: just add the missing field (e.g. 'customer_count') again, then delete the order rule (hold Shift and click the column name) and then delete the field again.